# Import "rest_framework_swagger.views" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I wanted to implement swagger in Django rest framework, for that I install django-rest-swagger and register in setting.py but while importing in url.py it show error:-

```
"Import "rest_framework_swagger.views" could not be resolved.
```

How can I use rest_framework_swagger?

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling this way.
Example :

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
```

Instead of get_swagger_view call the view you require.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons but the truth is you shouldn't be using a project that's read-only for over 2.5 years.

Try [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) or [drf-spectacular](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular) instead.

Anyway, if you installed the lib you're talking about with

```
pip install django-rest-swagger
```

it should be available in your environment. Make sure you see it in `pip freeze`.

Comment: I tried using drf-yasg and i got same import error